# How can I get classification assignments from mclust?

Tags: classification, cluster-analysis

Looking around I see that I can use cutree() with a hclust() model.  Is it possible to use this function on a mclust() model to get the classification assignments for each observation?

I want to do a cluster analysis using mclust(), but have never found a way to then simply get a data table of ID and Classification.  I would like to be able to use the classification as a grouping variable to then explore differences and similarities among clusters that were not part of the segmentation solution.  I have previously only been able to do this with Latent Gold, and couldn't find a method within R itself.

UPDATE: It looks like the $classification is where this information is headed.  I guess the only thing I really want is confirmation that the row orders are consistent from the data.frame that goes in, so that if I just cbind() it's attached to the correct observation.  Is row order preserved in this way?

Comment: I thought it's in the vignette? something like this:  ```mdl = Mclust(iris[,-5],3) ; mdl$classification``` ?